# Upgrading Hadoop from version CDH4 to CDH5

Tags: hadoop, cloudera, cloudera-manager

I need to upgrade Hadoop from CDH4 to CDH5. I have 5 nodes.

Can I upgrade using Cloudera Manager using parcels?

What is the easiest way to upgrade Hadoop? Can someone provide me steps?

Thanks,

Raj Baba

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Cloudera hadoop distribution, Cloudera Manager(CM) and CDH are different components. For upgrading CDH4 to CDH5, you would need to upgrade your Cloudera Manager version to CM5 first. **You cannot use parcels for upgrading your Cloudera Manager version as this is the base component**. Depends on your Linux distribution, tools (yum/apt) can be used for upgrading your CM.

If you are using CentOS or RHEL, you may use yum for upgrading your CM, update your `/etc/yum.repos.d/cloudera-manager.repo` file as follows :

```
[cloudera-manager]
# Packages for Cloudera Manager, Version 5, on RedHat or CentOS 6 x86_64              
name=Cloudera Manager
baseurl=http://archive-primary.cloudera.com/cm5/redhat/6/x86_64/cm/5.2.0/
gpgkey = http://archive.cloudera.com/cm5/redhat/6/x86_64/cm/RPM-GPG-KEY-cloudera    
gpgcheck = 0
```

After updating this file, you may use the command `yum upgrade cloudera-manager-*` for upgrading.

Once CM is CM5, for upgrading CDH4 to CDH5 parcel is the best option. Following cloudera documentation can be used for upgrading

http://www.cloudera.com/content/cloudera/en/documentation/core/latest/topics/cm_mc_upgrade_tocdh5_using_parcels.html